# Linear programming using python or excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.7, linear-programming

I have a question, here is the deal.

The company manufactures two-unit home air conditioners, which have a capacity of 350 units per month. The production cost of the air conditioner in Drive 1 is 30000 USD, and in Drive 2 it is 27000 USD. The price of the stored devices is 2800 USD for each started month. Assessment demand for the next three months is 400, 500 and 600 devices. Determined the optimal number of devices that should produce each drive in the next three months, with at least 50 devices being manufactured in each facility.

Now I came up with this

**Can anyone help me to transfer this in python code or excel**

[Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80k62.png) **Have a look please updated!**

What I need is someone to point me if I'm on a good track and to explain to me how to transfer this problem to Python using SciPy or some other libraries.

Thanks in advance and happy coding.
And yeah I don't need this for school I just can't let it go now once I started doing it.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.cvxpy.org/

Comment: Sorry, this Python question. Edited, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing an instance of the **capacitated lot-sizing problem** over 3 time periods. Modelwise, you need more variables to model the production in *each period t = 1,2,3.*, as well as auxiliary variables to capture the storage costs.

Please check out the PySCIPOpt Example code

https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/examples/finished/lotsizing_lazy.py

that should do what you want (to some extent). Unfortunately, the corresponding section of the [SCIP Book](https://scipbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lotsizing.html) hasn't been written, yet, but you should find enough tertiary literature on lot-sizing, if needed. The book may help you to understand some other concepts behind PySCIPOpt by browsing the parts that have already been written.

Comment: I added more variables if you can tell me what you think now that would be perfect. Thanks

Comment: Probably there is some confusion about the term 'variables'. I would expect that your model should contain at least six variables, namely x_1,1, x_1,2, x_1,3 to capture the individual production of drive 1 in the three periods 1,2,3, and another three variables for drive 2. I don't see that in your model.

Comment: Your shared mathematical optimization model looks almost correct. The only problem are the if-conditions. You may realize that they are not necessary. You can replace the first condition by p1 >= x_1 + x_2 - 400, and p1 >= 0. The latter inequality (nonnegativity) is an implicit assumption made by all solvers that I know. The same for the second if-condition regarding p_2.